Is it legal under GDPR for a website owner to link to their Google Calendar or WhatsApp for scheduling and communication?
I sometimes see websites that provide links to external services such as Google Calendar and WhatsApp for appointment scheduling and communication purposes. I also noticed these sites rarely document these links in their privacy policy and don't either provide a confirmation message that pops up on click to request user consent before actually redirecting them to the third party website.
The links to these services are proeminently displayed on these websites.
Given that the actual data processing and handling would occur on the platforms of Google Calendar or WhatsApp, and not within the website itself, are these links legal under GDPR?
If not, what steps should be implemented in order for these links to be GDPR-compliant?
e.g. adding an info message warning the user that they are about to leave the site for (name of the third party entity), or update their privacy policy in some way, or something else?
While this question applies to websites hosted in the EU in general, I would be particularly interested in answers that also account for French law and websites geographically hosted in France.

If the answer is "no", what would you expect navigating the internet to be like?  This would have to apply to all external links on a site.  The hosting site wouldn't be able to reasonably modify their privacy policy, given that the external link could change behavior at any time.  Overall, this would turn into an even larger compliance nightmare than the GDPR already is.  Note that any interactive warning would require JavaScript, which the user can turn off.

@Clockwork-Muse It would be like most US Government websites that have a non-government link warning.

@user71659 - that's tucked away somewhere else, and doesn't show up in response to clicking any of the external links.  Which you could do, I suppose, but... The larger problem, really, is that any sort of notification about this just becomes click-through noise, like the cookie popups and other notifications.  Nobody is actually going to read it, and since they still want/need the information on the other end they still have to go to the other site anyways.

@Clockwork-Muse It's not "tucked away", as described, the icon shows up after all external links.

Thank you for your answers user71659 and @Clockwork-Muse. So just to be clear, the fact that the website owner provides a link to say WhatsApp and then processes user data on this platform instead of directly in the website doesn't have to be documented in the website privacy policy (or require any kind of warning) ? Intuitively I would say no, but i really want to make sure I understand how external links are regulated in GDPR.
Also if you can answer this, could you please post an answer instead of a comment so that I can accept it?

I have no idea one way or the other about whether external links of that sort are regulated.  GDPR has been nightmarish in some ways (especially looking in from the outside).
